# Using Vue CLI 3 on XAMPP

Tags: vuejs2, xampp, vue-cli-3

**A little background..**

As mentioned before in https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-make-webpack-vue-work-on-xampp/33808. **And it works** *when I put my Vue project directly in htdocs like this.*

```
 htdocs/
  | - css/
  | - js/
  | etc..
```

However I'm using it differently, here's my current file structure in the `htdocs`.

```
htdocs/
 | - project1/
 |    | - css/
 |    | - some other stuff for project1
 | - project2/
 |    | - css/
 |    | - some other stuff for project2
 | - vue-project/ (Where I wanted my Vue went to)
 |    | - css/
 |    | - stuff..
```

The error I get when I put `dist/` of my vue project directly to `htdocs/vue-project` is 404, because they directly went back to the root file (root is `htdocs/`), in which it doesn't find the required file to launch Vue Project!

**What I wanted**

Anything that can launch the project in `htdocs/vue-project/`. Would accept any answer configuring either settings in the Vue/Webpack OR from XAMPP itself. If you need additional information please do ask in the comment section.

And if it turns out there are no other way, then I would accept answers involving XAMPP configuration on how to start a server in a different directories. Like start a server in `htdocs`, and `other-file` would be great as well.

Comment: Have you used vue-router in your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Vue CLI before 3.x**

Try changing `assetsPublicPath` under `build` object in `config/index.js`. Then append your folder name there. Similiar issue that might help https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-js-webpack-deployment-for-xaamp-testing/28970

And if vue-router used then add ROUTER_BASE.
https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#base

**For Vue CLI 3**

1. Create `vue.config.js` inside your vue-projects
2. Inside it simply add the following

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: "/{path-to-your-vue-project}"
}
```

For more information please refer to this docs https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath

Comment: Could you specify where the `config/index.js` is? I tried to look for `config` on my current Vue Project, but it's too many, could you specify it a little bit more? **P.S.** I think that was option for Vue CLI *before* 3, mine is Vue CLI 3. So I don't seem to find that directories..

Comment: Ok in vue cli3 it's not there.Have you gone through this ?https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath